# PluginsCMDWorker exception in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to jmeter. When I run my test with Graphs Generator plugin I get this exception.

```
ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kg/apc/jmeter/PluginsCMDWorker
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:146) ~[JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar:?]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.listener.GraphsGeneratorListener.testEnded(GraphsGeneratorListener.java:137) ~[JMeterPlugins-Extras.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfEnd(StandardJMeterEngine.java:227) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:495) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    ... 5 more
2018-04-05 13:33:26,076 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.desktop/javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultDocumentEventUndoableWrapper cannot be cast to java.desktop/javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument$DefaultDocumentEvent
    at jsyntaxpane.CompoundUndoMan.undoableEditHappened(CompoundUndoMan.java:61) ~[jsyntaxpane-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireUndoableEditUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsText.showTextResponse(RenderAsText.java:36) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.RenderAsText.renderResult(RenderAsText.java:31) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:392) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.ViewResultsFullVisualizer.valueChanged(ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java:365) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at javax.swing.JTree.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JTree$TreeSelectionRedirector.valueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.notifyPathChange(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPaths(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeSelectionModel.setSelectionPath(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JTree.setSelectionPath(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.selectPathForEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.handleSelection(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Also, I added the Plugin Manager .jar file but when I click on Plugin Manager I get a Connection timed out error and it does not redirect me to the Plugin Window.

Comment: It would help others to reproduce and help solve your problem if you included a minimal complete example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/), the recommended way of installing it is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Command Line Tool]

If for some reason you cannot use the Plugins Manager you can always download jar from https://jmeter-plugins.org/?search=jpgc-cmd, drop it to "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick it up.